# $http.get from 2 jsons Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I try to get data from 2 jsons :

1st 'names.json':

```
  [
        {
            "name": "AAAAAA",
            "down": "False"

        },

        {
            "name": "BBBBBB",
            "down": "45%"
        },
        {
            "name": "CCCCC",
            "down": "12%"
        }
]
```

Second 'data.json'

```
[
         {
            "data": "25-12-2014"
        }
]
```

Javascript:

```
app.service('service', function($http){
        this.getNames = function () {
            var data =  $http.get('data,json', { cache: false});
            var names =  $http.get('names.json', { cache: false});
            return names;
            return data;
            };
        });

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service) {
var promise = service.getNames();
            promise.then(function (data) {
            $scope.datas = data.data;       
            console.log($scope.datas);
            });
        })
```

HTML

```
div ng-controller="FirstCtrl"
     <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="name in datas">
            <td>{{name.name}}</td>
            <td>{{name.data}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

In my console.log and table i only see data from json "names.json", but i want also see data from "data.json"
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your second **return** wont be hit

Comment: A function can only have one return....anything after that won't execute because the function will be exited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should return both the promise together, you can't have two return in a single function. In this case `$q.all` would help.

**Code**

```
//inject $q in service function
this.getNames = function () {
    var data =  $http.get('data,json', { cache: false});
    var names =  $http.get('names.json', { cache: false});
    return $q.all([data, names]);
};
```

**Controller**

```
var promise = service.getNames();
promise.then(function (data) {
    $scope.datas = data[0].data;
    $scope.names = data[1].data;
});
```

Comment: and remember to inject `$q`

Comment: @charlietfl added comment there, Thanks for heads up :)

Comment: best solution ! you want faster than me :)

Comment: `$q.all` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @zeroflagL don't think so there would be any difference in there working.. but It will be more verbose. Updated :) Thanks

Comment: They are different. Plus: You can pass an object to `$q.all`, like `$q.all({data, names})` and then read it with `$scope.names = data.names.data;`, so you don't have to remember the index. Particularly nice  with ES6: `function ({data, names}) { $scope.names = names.data;`.

Comment: @PankajParkar Ok thanks, but i must show in table data, which is in another array

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

```
app.service('service', function($http) {
    return{
        getData : function(){
            return $http.get('data,json', { cache: false });
        },
        getNames : function(){
            return $http.get('names.json', { cache: false });
        }
    }

});

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, service, $q) {
    $q.all([service.getData(), service.getNames()]).then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response[0].data;
        $scope.names = response[1].data:
    });
})
```

Comment: if OP want both data in same times this is not usefull. Pankaj Parkar solution is the best because it return both in same time ( imagine if you want 5 files data )

Comment: yep, your approach also work. i don't know if it is  better to do the $q promises waiting in service side, in case you need this service multiple time maybe better to factorise the code in service side.